# htaccess internal rewrite for URL with query params

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a php file `/var/www/somepath/index.php` which handles requests to

```
http://example.com/somepath/?q=query
```

I'd like the same file to handle requests to

```
http://example.com/some/other/path/?q=query
http://example.com/another/path/?q=query
http://example.com/yet/another/path/?q=query
```

I do not want to copy the php file into multiple locations in the filesystem. I thought using internal rewrite rules would be a better way to do do it. Here is what I put in top-level `.htaccess` file `/var/www/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^some/other/path /somepath/%{QUERY_STRING} [PT]
```

But it does not work. I get a 404 for http://example.com/some/other/path/?q=query

I know that mod_rewrite is enabled because I have external rewrite rules (301 and 302 redirects) in the same .htaccess files and those work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place this rule **as your very first rule** in the site root .htaccess which will handle any URL with `?q=` query parameter:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)q= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ somepath/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you anubhava. If the user browses to http://example.com/some/other/path/?q=query what makes "some/other/path" part of the URL disappear? We did not match it as part of the rewrite rule, so it stays in the URL?
Or does old URL get completely wiped out? If so, won't the query string be wiped out as well?

Comment: This is an internal rewrite, no information gets lost. If you check `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` it will show `/some/other/path/?q=query`, `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` will show `q=query` and finally if you check `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]` it will show rewritten path i.e. `/somepath/index.php`